# Mysql Spatial Extension. How to check if Linestring CONTAINS a Point?

Tags: mysql, spatial, spatial-index

I'm trying to determine if Linestring have Point.... f.e.

```
SET ls = geomfromtext('LINESTRING(1 0,3 0)');
SET p = geomfromtext('POINT(2 0)');
```

if i do `CONTAINS(ls,p)` i have true. but there is no point (2 0) in line

i need exactly containing. is there any function for it?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `intersect`?

Comment: it gives wrong result. see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check out the following reference on [this article](http://www.tu-chemnitz.de/docs/mysql-man/manual_GIS_spatial_extensions_in_MySQL.html)

- [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84420/1)

  `SET @ls = 'LineString(1 0,3 0)';`

  `SET @xs = geomfromtext(@ls);`

  `SET @p = geomfromtext('POINT(2 0)');`

  `SELECT MBRWithin(@xs,@p);`

Sorry I have given the wrong link.

results

```
MBRWITHIN(@XS,@P)
0
```

Looking at your line 1 0, 3 0 --> 2 0 point exists on it.

[image]

Comment: i tried all functions from documentation and non of them do what i need.

Comment: hi I believe you indeed have ;) it seems `MBRWITHIN` is what you are looking for. I have given the wrong link. Coz when I tested, `intersect` didn't seem to satisfy. But `MBRWITHIN` does. I am interested in this area too. So if you find this is not the answer, but something else, please share :)

Comment: MBRWITHIN gives the same result. see my second answer above

Comment: I belive `MBRWITHIN` is not applicable to your case. If you are looking at a LineString that has 2 points -> in your example the line contains point(2 0) within (1 0, 3 0).

Comment: Then you can extract the best point out using `POINTN` and search. I was devistated that none of the functions are working to see if a point contains in a line/polygon....etc... ;) Worst come to worst, you can just save those linestring points into a colunn in a temp table and then check them agains the point u have... or in the along the same logic... you are in mysql, might as well as try that too...

Comment: yes i did already. can you pls check my function below and comment why it is very slow?

Answer (score 0):

i tried all functions from documentation and non of them do what i need. 
f.e.

```
SELECT ASTEXT(path) FROM paths WHERE INTERSECTS(path, GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(604 0)'))
```

gives "wrong" results

```
LINESTRING(572 0,600 0,601 0,602 0,603 0,604 0,605 0,606 0,607 0,608 0,402 0)
LINESTRING(402 0,609 0,610 0,611 0,612 0,613 0,614 0,615 0,616 0,617 0,618 0,619 0,620 0,621 0,622 0,623 0)
LINESTRING(359 0,449 0,801 0,422 0,802 0,803 0,498 0)
LINESTRING(572 0,795 0,796 0,797 0,798 0,799 0,800 0,345 0,359 0)
LINESTRING(792 0,768 0,793 0,794 0,572 0)
LINESTRING(342 0,904 0,905 0,906 0)
LINESTRING(912 0,914 0,915 0,916 0,341 0)
LINESTRING(344 0,917 0,918 0,919 0,920 0,800 0)
LINESTRING(918 0,922 0,923 0,924 0,925 0,926 0,927 0,343 0)
LINESTRING(940 0,947 0,948 0,949 0,604 0)
```

MBRWITHIN gives the same result

i wrote a function, but it is very-very slow:

```
FUNCTION `IDIL`(`id` INT, `line` LINESTRING) RETURNS INT(1)
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE p1X INT(20); 
DECLARE p1Y INT(20); 
DECLARE p1 POINT; 
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE result INT(1) DEFAULT 0; 
SET n = NUMPOINTS(line); 
WHILE i<n DO 
    SET p1 = POINTN(line, (i+1)); 
    SET p1X = X(p1); 
    SET p1Y = Y(p1); 
    IF p1X=id OR p1Y=id THEN RETURN 1; END IF; 
    SET i = i + 1; 
END WHILE; 
RETURN result; 
    END$$
```

Comment: i think it slow because i do not use spatial index. how can i use it inside my function?

Comment: it tooks 17 seconds for 1000 rows

Comment: I am mainly depending on SQLFiddle on a different machine where nothing can be installed. I will try your function. In the mean time, could you please look into this as well [poor performance when using spacial index in mysql](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/poor-performance-when-using-spatial-indexes-in-mysql) I am thinking, this could be the place you would want to post your question. I will also see if I can move it there. Because then a real expert can help you out :)